# submit multiple forms with one submit button using useForm

Tags: reactjs, form-submit, react-hook-form, use-form

Is it possible to submit multiple forms with one submit button using useForm hook? If possible, can someone tell me how can I do? I use two useForm instances for form creation but I only can submit one form value.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution?